# Migrating from bitcoin core to bitcoind

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, installation

I have installed `bitcoin core` in my `ubuntu-14.04` which is working fine.
Now I want to install `bitcoind` in the same Machine. Can I install `bitcoind` along with `bitcoin core` or I need to uninstall `bitcoin core` from my machine.

**What should I do to migrate from `bitcoin core` to `bitcoind`?**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are identical in functionality, data store, and wallet storage.

You can run one or the other, but not both at one time (this will throw an error if you attempt it).

Comment: What should I do to migrate from bitcoin core to bitcoind?

Comment: Literally nothing, start either `bitcoind` or `bitcoin-qt` as desired.

Comment: do I need to uninstall bitcoin-qt

Comment: No, you do not.